# Change Pivot PivotHeaderItem FontSize with VisualStateManager Windows 10

Tags: xaml, windows-10, windows-10-universal, visualstatemanager

I have a `Pivot` with the following style

```
  <Page.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem"  x:Name="PivotHeaderItem800">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/garfield the cat.ttf#garfield the cat"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Unselected" To="UnselectedLocked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                    <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked" To="Unselected" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Duration="0" To="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                            <!-- original value {ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush} -->
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <!--<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />-->
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <!--<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />-->
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Using `VisualStateManager` I want to reduce the `FontSize` to 24 when the `AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500"` is true. How do I create the new style in `Page.Resource` correctly? I want something like

```
    <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem"  x:Name="PivotHeaderItem500" BasedOn="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItem800}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
    </Style>
```

Visual Studio complains `The key is already defined in this scope.`

In my `VisualStateManager` currently I have the following. Once the new style is created I want to apply it under `VisualStateMin500`.

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin800">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualState500">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="textBlockTitle.(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Thickness>20,36,20,24</Thickness>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Target="textBlockTitle.(TextBlock.FontSize)" Value="48"/>
                    <Setter Target="rootPivot.(FrameworkElement.Width)" Value="500"/>
                    <Setter Target="listView0.(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Thickness>18</Thickness>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>

                    <Setter Target="listView1.(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Thickness>18</Thickness>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Target="listView2.(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Thickness>18</Thickness>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Target="listView3.(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Thickness>18</Thickness>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Target="listView4.(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Thickness>18</Thickness>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </VisualState.Setters>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

My `Pivot` xaml is as follows

```
  <RelativePanel>
        <control:ProgressRingWithText RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockTitle" Text="Leaderboards" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="24,48,24,28" FontSize="64"/>

        <Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" RelativePanel.Below="textBlockTitle" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Width="800" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                                          InputConverter="{StaticResource SelectionChangedEventArgsConverter}"
                                          InputConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=rootPivot, Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <PivotItem x:Name="pivotItem0" Header="{Binding LevelVeryEasyName}" >
                <ListView x:Name="listView0" ItemsSource="{Binding ScoreList}" IsItemClickEnabled="False" Margin="24">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <control:PivotListViewItemTemplate />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </PivotItem>

            <PivotItem  x:Name="pivotItem1" Header="{Binding LevelEasyName}">
                <ListView x:Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding ScoreList}" IsItemClickEnabled="False" Margin="24">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <control:PivotListViewItemTemplate />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem x:Name="pivotItem2" Header="{Binding LevelMediumName}">
                <ListView x:Name="listView2" ItemsSource="{Binding ScoreList}" IsItemClickEnabled="False" Margin="24">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <control:PivotListViewItemTemplate />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem x:Name="pivotItem3" Header="{Binding LevelHardName}">
                <ListView x:Name="listView3" ItemsSource="{Binding ScoreList}" IsItemClickEnabled="False" Margin="24">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <control:PivotListViewItemTemplate />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem x:Name="pivotItem4" Header="{Binding LevelInsaneName}">
                <ListView x:Name="listView4" ItemsSource="{Binding ScoreList}" IsItemClickEnabled="False" Margin="24">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <control:PivotListViewItemTemplate />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </RelativePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Binding it directly in Header. Change it to below.

```
<PivotItem.Header>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding LevelVeryEasyName}" x:Name="PivotItem0"/>
</PivotItem.Header>
```

This way you will get full access to Pivot Header.

Now your setter will be

```
<Setter Target="PivotItem0.(TextBlock.FontSize)" Value="24"/>
```

See if it works. Let me know the outcome.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. Here what I did  `<PivotItem x:Name="PivotItem0">
                    <PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LevelVeryEasyName}" x:Name="PivotItemHeader0" FontSize="40"/>
                </PivotItem.Header>` . Then `       <Setter Target="PivotItemHeader0.(TextBox.FontSize)" Value="32"/>` . I've to removed the `FontSize` setter in  `<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">`. Another thing is I tried doing the same to adjust the `Margin` but it does not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Margin of individual headers of pivot?

Comment: The whole headers margin

Comment: Don't change individual items margin separately. Change the Margin of whole pivot. <Setter Target="rootPivot.(Pivot.Margin)" Value="0,-50,0,0"/>